# Create Unity variable text from JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest, unity-game-engine

Searching for this problem only seems to bring up very complex solutions, and I feel there is something simple I'm not getting in the syntax.
I've managed to change my text linking to a weather api, but need to do the same from my RestfulDB api.
Here are my scripts, this first one works...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ForecastController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject helloworld;
    IEnumerator AdjustSkyToWeather()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string weatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=2000,au&APPID=d38ee94695788506fb6b2be25a1b7303";

            WWW weatherWWW = new WWW(weatherUrl);
            yield return weatherWWW;

            JSONObject tempData = new JSONObject(weatherWWW.text);

            Debug.Log(tempData["list"][0]["main"]["humidity"]);
            helloworld.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = tempData["list"][0]["main"]["humidity"].ToString();


            yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(AdjustSkyToWeather());
    }
}
```

This is the one with the issue...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class iotAPIScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject iotText;
    IEnumerator GetIoTData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string iotDBURL = "https://iotar01-ad83.restdb.io/rest/test-collection/5be9faed3dca561f00004ab7";

            WWW iotDB = new WWW(iotDBURL);
            yield return iotDB;

            JSONObject tempData = new JSONObject(iotDB.text);

            Debug.Log(tempData["iottest03"]);
            iotText.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = tempData["iottest03"].ToString();


            yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
        }
    }
}
```

The end result is supposed to have the "iotAR" text change to "10011" when it picks up the api.

This video shows how it looks: https://youtu.be/wZD56iL4UJU

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**

This is the JSON source:

```
 {
    "_id":"5be9faed3dca561f00004ab7",
    "Test value":"101",
    "testRound02":"0010101",
    "iottest03":"10011"
}
```

This is what the consoles show, no errors, but not picking up the RestDB...

[image: console]

Comment: the second one shows me `401 unauthorized` .. so please add the supposed received JSON to your question.

Comment: In that case, maybe it's also blocking Unity from receiving it?
This is the JSON source:

{"_id":"5be9faed3dca561f00004ab7","Test value":"101","testRound02":"0010101","iottest03":"10011"}

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get any error? (Please add additional information to your question not here in the comments - see my edit to your question)

Comment: Thanks derHugo, added the image of the console above. It shows no errors, but doesn't up the RestDB.